Different v-models for v-select in a for loop
I have data like this:
products: [
    {
      name: "Camera",
      subProducts: [
         {
          name: "Type",
          types: [
             {
              name: "CAM A",
              value: "A",
             },
             {
              name: "CAM B",
              value: "B",
             },
           ],
          },

          {
           name: "Recorder",
           types: [
             {
              name: "Yes",
              value: 1,
             },
             {
              name: "No",
              value: 0,
             },
            ],
           },

          ],
        },

I want to have a number of v-selects depending on the number of subProducts. Each of these v-selects will display a type group.
For this example, there will be 2 v-selecet where in the first one you can select between CAM A / CAM B. In the second one you can choose between Yes/No. I did this using computed props:
computed: {
 comModels: function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
    if (this.products[i].name == this.selectedMainGroup) {
      return this.products[i].subProducts;
    }
  }
  return "nothing";
 },
},

And this is my v-select with for:
          <v-select
            v-for="product in comModels"
            :itemProps="itemProps"
            v-model="selectedModel"
            :items="product.types"
            :label="product.name"
            dense
            solo
            outlined
            hide-details
            class="ma-2"
          >
          </v-select>

The problem is when I choose one of them v-model only holds one of them and the other one gets deleted. How can I keep both of their values while being flexible because there may be more subProducts

The v-model of tow selects  need to be independent ,so change the  selectedModel to an Object,and use   v-model="selectedModel[product.name]"
data(){
        return {
            selectedModel:{}
        }
    }

...
 <v-select
            v-for="product in comModels"
            :itemProps="itemProps"
            v-model="selectedModel[product.name]"
            :items="product.types"
            :label="product.name"
            dense
            solo
            outlined
            hide-details
            class="ma-2"
          >
          </v-select>

